# how do i use two lists in robot framework keyword?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, robotframework, helper

I would like to create a keyword that has 2 lists, where list 1 would be the fields and list 2 would be the field values.

Examples:

I have 3 fields:

Name: John
Birth: 10/26/2022
City: João Pessoa

Keywords:

fill in the fields
[Arguments] @{fields} @{values}

however, it is not possible to do this, Robot returns the following message:

Cannot have multiple varargs.

can anybody help me?

```
I don't see any other way to do this.

If anyone can help me, I would be very happy.

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-in-zip-loop
Check below code snippet, which has two list and there are two ways to iterate. Hope this is what you're looking for.

**Updated Code as per your comment:**

When you pass two list variable, use "$" instead of "@". I've executed below code it is working, so please try the updated one.

```
*** Settings ***
Library   Collections

*** Keywords ***
FOR-IN-ZIP
    [Arguments]    ${NUMBERS}    ${NAMES}
    Log List    ${NUMBERS}    level=INFO
    Log List    ${NAMES} 
    FOR    ${number}    ${name}    IN ZIP    ${NUMBERS}    ${NAMES}
        Log Many    ${number}    ${name}
    END

*** Test Cases ***
Test Multiple List As Argument
    @{NUMBERS} =    Create List    ${1}    ${2}    ${5}
    @{NAMES} =    Create List    one     two     five
    FOR-IN-ZIP     ${NUMBERS}    ${NAMES}
```

**Old Code:**

```
*** Variables ***
@{NUMBERS}       ${1}    ${2}    ${5}
@{NAMES}         one     two     five
*** Test Cases ***
Iterate over two lists manually
    ${length}=    Get Length    ${NUMBERS}
    FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    ${length}
        Log Many    ${NUMBERS}[${index}]    ${NAMES}[${index}]
    END
FOR-IN-ZIP
    FOR    ${number}    ${name}    IN ZIP    ${NUMBERS}    ${NAMES}
        Log Many    ${number}    ${name}
    END
```

Comment: Hey!

Thank you for your comment.

However, I would like to pass 2 list as an argument to keyword, so that it can read what is in each list and act on what is in each of the actions.

However, the robot does not accept 2 lists as an argument, so I would like to know if there is another way to accomplish this.

Comment: @HeloisaHorst I've added updated code, Please check and let me know